# Problema con función DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta en SQL la cual tiene los datos de año, mes, día como datos numéricos independientes (`YEAR, MONTH, DAY`) respectivamente.
Realizo la siguiente sentencia para obtener la fecha:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATE,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),RTRIM(LTRIM([DAY]))) + '-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),RTRIM(LTRIM([MONTH]))) +'-'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),RTRIM(LTRIM([YEAR])))),103),111) AS FECHA
```

Este dato lo quiero utilizar con una función `Datediff`

```
SELECT  T1.ITEM,T1.AREA,T1.YEAR,T1.MONTH,T1.DAY,T1.FECHA,T1.FECHA_ACTUAL,
        DATEDIFF(d,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T1.FECHA,111),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T1.FECHA_ACTUAL,111)) AS NUMERO
FROM CTE_DEMDIARIA AS T1
WHERE   DATEDIFF(d,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T1.FECHA,111),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T1.FECHA_ACTUAL,111))>0 AND 
        DATEDIFF(d,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T1.FECHA,111),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T1.FECHA_ACTUAL,111))<=15
```

En esta consulta existe un valor de venta diaria que es `QTY`, tengo un problema el momento que agrego la cantidad a la consulta me sale el siguiente error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

retiro la cantidad y ejecuta la sentencia sin problema...

Alguien quien me pueda apoyar con esta inquietud muchas gracias

Saludos.

Comment: Qué motor de base de datos estás usando?, se ve como SQL Server, pero mejor que lo agregues y la versión también

Comment: Y el error te aparece cuando agregas `QTY` dónde?

Comment: Ya quitaste la función del CONVERT?, eso hace que tu campo FECHA_ACTUAL (quiero creer que es de tipo DateTime) se convierta a un string, si usas la función DateDiff usala con el tipo de dato nativo que en este caso es DateTime, el resultado que te dé lo puedes formatear o presentar de la forma que tu quieras.

Comment: Intenta cambiando el orden de los datos, primero el año luego el mes y finalmente el dia

Comment: Estoy utilizando SQL Server 2014.
El error me aparece cuando añado a la consulta que les detallo la cantidad
SELECT T1.ITEM,T1.AREA,T1.YEAR,T1.MONTH,T1.DAY,T1.FECHA,T1.FECHA_ACTUAL,
  DATEDIFF(d,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T1.FECHA,111),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T1.FECHA_ACTUAL,111)) AS NUMERO
FROM CTE_DEMDIARIA AS T1
WHERE DATEDIFF(d,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T1.FECHA,111),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T1.FECHA_ACTUAL,111))>0 AND 
  DATEDIFF(d,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T1.FECHA,111),CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T1.FECHA_ACTUAL,111))<=15

Comment: Kevin - También realice tu sugerencia y el error persiste

Comment: Lamak - como detallo en la consulta esta ITEM-AREA-AÑO-MES-DIA-FECHA , FECHA_ACTUAL, NUMERO(QUE ES LA RESTA DE LAS DOS ANTERIORES) .... Al agregar la cantidad a esto me da el error

Comment: @DaSa para crear un `Date` a partir del año, mes y día puedes usar la función [DATEFROMPARTS (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) que está a partir de SQL Server 2012 y no considerarlo como cadena. Sería bueno que indiques que resultado obtienes del CTE `CTE_DEMDIARIA`.

Comment: @Davlio detallo el script completo para el analisis y ayuda
WITH
CTE_DEMDIARIA AS
(
SELECT [ITEM]
      ,[AREA]
      ,[YEAR]
      ,[MONTH]
      ,[DAY]
      ,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR,MONTH,DAY) AS FECHA
      ,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),112) AS FECHA_ACTUAL
      ,[QTY]
      ,[LO]
      ,[EXQTY]
      ,[EXLO]
  FROM [750_MSM_CD+TIENDAS_OR].[dbo].[DAILYDEM_DAY]
  WHERE ITEM = '44270' AND AREA='29'
  ),

Realizo un CTE que le llamo CTE_DEMDIARIA en el cual agrego los campos de fecha datos de la tabla de Demanda Diaria

Comment: @Davlio del CTE_DEMDIARIA realizo un nuevo CTE que lo denomino CTE_DEMPERIODO con el cual deseo extraer únicamente la Demanda de los últimos 15 días, para ello utilizo la función DATEIFF

CTE_DEMPERIODO AS
(
SELECT T1.ITEM,T1.AREA,T1.YEAR,T1.MONTH,T1.DAY,T1.FECHA,T1.FECHA_ACTUAL
  ,DATEDIFF(d,T1.FECHA,T1.FECHA_ACTUAL) AS NUMERO
  --,T1.QTY
FROM CTE_DEMDIARIA AS T1
WHERE DATEDIFF(d,T1.FECHA,T1.FECHA_ACTUAL)>0 AND 
  DATEDIFF(d,T1.FECHA,T1.FECHA_ACTUAL)<=15
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE_DEMPERIODO AS T1
ORDER BY T1.ITEM,T1.AREA,T1.FECHA

El momento que agrego la cantidad QTY (da error)

Comment: @DaSa, recuerda que puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/92131/edit) y agregues más detalle. Al decirte "resultado", es para saber como son los registros que obtienes como resultado de tus consultas.

Comment: @Davlio te detallo el resultado
ITEM AREA YEAR MONTH DAY FECHA FECHA_ACTUAL NUMERO
44270 29 2017 7 18 2017-07-18 2017-08-02 15
44270 29 2017 7 19 2017-07-19 2017-08-02 14
44270 29 2017 7 20 2017-07-20 2017-08-02 13
44270 29 2017 7 21 2017-07-21 2017-08-02 12
44270 29 2017 7 22 2017-07-22 2017-08-02 11
44270 29 2017 7 23 2017-07-23 2017-08-02 10
44270 29 2017 7 24 2017-07-24 2017-08-02 9
44270 29 2017 7 25 2017-07-25 2017-08-02 8
44270 29 2017 7 26 2017-07-26 2017-08-02 7
44270 29 2017 7 27 2017-07-27 2017-08-02 6
44270 29 2017 7 28 2017-07-28 2017-08-02 5

Comment: @Davlio
44270 29 2017 7 29 2017-07-29 2017-08-02 4
44270 29 2017 7 30 2017-07-30 2017-08-02 3
44270 29 2017 7 31 2017-07-31 2017-08-02 2
44270 29 2017 8 1 2017-08-01 2017-08-02 1

ese es el resultado de los 15 dias, el momento que agrego la cantidad QTY... me muestra el error

Mens. 289, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1
Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.

Agradezco el apoyo, la verdad no le encuentro el  problema

Comment: @DaSa ingresa a: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/92131/edit para que puedas editar tu pregunta y agregas lo que indicas en los comentarios. De esa manera puedan ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

La forma que tengo para hacer esto es la siguiente:

```
DECLARE @Dia      INT
DECLARE @Mes      INT
DECLARE @Ano      INT

SELECT  @Dia = 2, 
        @Mes = 1, 
        @Ano = 2017

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Ano * 10000 + @Mes + 100 + @Dia))
```

Es decir, sumo los valores de año * 10000 + los de mes * 100 + días, eso me genera un número `20170102` lo llevo a un `VARCHAR` y por último a un `DATETIME`. Tiene un único problema, en algún momento, si el año aumenta de dígitos va a superara el tamaño de un `INT` y va a fallar, seguramente para ese entonces ya no exista el planeta.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que en lugar del **111** en el *CONVERT* uses **112** cuyo [style](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) te dara un formato [que en Social MMSDN esta marcado como respuesta correcta](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/84a37a13-2905-416b-91e2-dd14c76ff13e/convertir-campo-datetime-en-date-sin-hora-en-la-clausula-where-sql-server?forum=sqlserveres).

Como bien ha mencionado en respuesta **Julx** no tiene caso usar conversión a string si estas usando funciones para determinar la diferencia de "tu interes"; como tal al parecer son fechas; te afectaria si incluyen hora y claro por ejemplo no te considerara transcurrio un día si la fecha a comparar fuesen (dia/mes/año horas:minutos -en formato de 24 hrs): **01/08/2017 13:00 hrs** con **02/08/2017 12:00 hrs** toda vez que no llega o supera 24 hrs.

Comment: _Utiliza los comentarios para pedir más información o para sugerir mejoras._

Answer (score -3):

Prueba con esto:

```
DECLARE
  @Dia      int,
  @Mes      int,
  @Ano      int,
  @Fecha    datetime,
  @Hoy      datetime

SELECT @Dia = 2, @Mes = 7, @Ano = 2017, @Hoy = GETDATE()
SELECT @Fecha = CONCAT(@Ano, '-', @Mes, '-', @Dia)
SELECT DATEDIFF(Day, @Fecha, @Hoy)
```